# Are there specific rules or precendence while using '+=' to insert data into a Map in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to insert data into a mutble Map in Scala by splitting a string. The map has String as key & another mutable Map[Int,Int] as its value

```
var dm = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[Int, Int]]()
val c  = s.split(" ") // s = abc 0 -> c(0)=abc, c(1)=0
```

I am trying to add `c(0)` as the main key of `dm` & `c(1)` as the key of inner map and `1` as its value using the operator `+=`

```
dm += c(0) -> (c(1).toInt -> 1)
```

But I see this compilation error in the code at this line `dm += c(0) -> (c(1).toInt -> 1)`

```
Cannot resolve symbol +=
Error:(18, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]
                else dm += c(0) -> (c(1).toInt -> 1)
```

`c(0)` is a String, `c(1)` is being casted to Int and `1` is the right data type. But I don't understand why it says wrong datatypes are given. Am I missing any precedence or using thee paranthesis wrong ?
Could anyone let me know how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(c(1).toInt -> 1)` isn't a `Map` (mutable or otherwise), it's a tuple.

But a tuple *can* be turned into a `Map` with a single key->value pair.

```
dm += c(0) -> mutable.Map(c(1).toInt -> 1)
```

BTW, `dm` is already mutable so there's no reason to make it a `var`.

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to update (`+=`) both Maps then you need the `+=` op on both Maps.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val dm =  //with existing content
  mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[Int, Int]]("abc" -> mutable.Map(9->9))
  .withDefaultValue(mutable.Map()) //and an empty Map as default

val c = "abc 0".split(" ")
val d = "xyz 5".split(" ")

dm += c(0) -> (dm(c(0)) += (c(1).toInt -> 1))
dm += d(0) -> (dm(d(0)) += (d(1).toInt -> 2))
//Map(xyz -> Map(5 -> 2), abc -> Map(0 -> 1, 9 -> 9))
```

Comment: The problem with this is, everytime I insert the value using mutable.Map(c(1).toInt -> 1), it replaces the existing Map inside the main Map. For ex: if I have Map("abc",(0->1,1->1)) and I run mutable.Map(c(1).toInt -> 1), it will replace all the inner keys and put a new Map there. I understand if the keys are same if it replaces but it replaces the existing values all the time.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's what your code appears to be doing (if it compiled). See my update.

Comment: I think this will result in KeyNotFound Exception due to this part: dm(c(0)) += (c(1).toInt -> 1) I can put the code in try catch and insert the data when I catch any exception but is it a good way to follow ?

Comment: The code, as posted, compiles, runs, and produces the commented result. What key do you "think" won't be found?

Comment: For example in c(0)=abc, c(1)=0, The code actually eliminates the problem I posted. Just thought that in 'dm += c(0) -> (dm(c(0)) += (c(1).toInt -> 1))' the part: 'dm(c(0))' gives the issue as abc is not yet saved in the Map and hence results in KeyNotFound exception. Thats what I was saying in my prev comment about try/catch usage.

Comment: I will take it up from here. Thanks for the answer and other clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

`+=` method accepts argument type `(K, V)` where `K` is key type of your declared mutable map and `V` - is value. You see this compilation error, because in your case `V` is `mutable.Map[Int,Int]` and not not `(Int, Int)` as your code declare to past a tuple.

So what you would like to do, is next:

```
var dm = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Map[Int, Int]]()
val c  = s.split(" ") // s = abc 0 -> c(0)=abc, c(1)=0

// get internal Map[Int, Int] or create new one if it does not exists for a key
val valueMap = dm.getOrElse(c(0), mutable.Map.empty[Int, Int])

// Append internal map with tuple of Int's 
valueMap += c(1).toInt -> 1

// Put map back to outer map, for the case if it did not exists before, or override it
dm += c(0) -> valueMap
```

Rule of thumb - try to avoid mutable structures as much as possible, and try to use immutable structures instead.

Hope this helps!